# Algorithm Analysis Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
def function(n):
    if n <= 1:
       return
    function(n / 2)
    function(n / 2)
```

I just wonder why this function have a O(n) runtime.

I see that every time this function get call it gonna reduce the size of the input by 2. So I think the runtime gonna be nlog(n) because it have call the function 2 time so it is n and it call it self but reduce the input by 2 so I think that is another logn.

Comment: It is reducing the size *by half*.  Try working out the actual count for some specific values of n (powers of 2 are cleaner) to see why it is actually O(n).

Comment: that second call negates any halving of input you had. If you call `function(16)`, it will end up calling `function(2)` 8 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified analysis ignoring the constant work done in the function (which isn't correct as pointed out in the comment, but will help understanding the steps). Since the function is calling itself on halved input twice, we can write the running time as

`T(n) = 2 * T(n/2)`

Expanding it further:

`T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) = 4 * T(n/4) = ... = K * T(n/K) = n * T(1)`

( We see it is getting the form of `K * T(n/K)`. The last element is `K*T(1)`, and since we have shown that `1 = n/K`, then `K` of the last element equals `n` )

Since `K(1)` is `O(1)`, then the `n*K(1)` is `O(n)`.

---

Now if we do consider the constant work in each call, we should rewrite it as following:

`T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + C`

Now expand:

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + C = 
= 2 * (2 * T(n/4) + C ) + C = 4 * T(n/4) + (2 + 1)*C =
= 4 * (2 * T(n/8) + C ) + C = 8 * T(n/8) + (4 + 1)*C =
...
= K * T(n/K) + (K/2 + 1) * C
```

Again, for the last element `K = n`, so
`T(n) = n * T(1) + (n/2 + 1) * C`

Both `n * T(1)` and `(n/2 + 1) * C` parts of the sum are `O(n)`, so overall complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: This isn't quite right; it omits the constant work done in each call. (To see why that matters, consider a function f that makes just *one* recursive call to f(n/2). If we ignore the constant work, we get T(n) = T(n/2) = T(n/4) = ... = T(1) and conclude that it runs in O(1) time, when in fact it runs in O(log n) time.)

Comment: @ruakh You are right. Let me add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The number of operations as a function of n is equal to

`2^(floor(log2(n)) + 1) - 1`

This can be seen by looking at a tree representation of the calls for n

Consider f(8):

```
                                       f(4)           1 
                                     /      \         +
                                   f(2)     f(2)      2
                                   / \     /   \      +
                                f(1) f(1) f(1) f(1)   4
                          _______________________________ 
                                = 2^(log2(4)+1) - 1 = 7 operations
```

But the case is the same for n = 5, 6, 7 because of the integer division truncation enforced by the `n<=1` condition in the algorithm, which is why we need the floor of the log as opposed to just the log.

If you consider the graph of the number of operations, you can see that it is bounded below by `n` and above by `2*n - 1` for all positive integer `n`:

[image]